# python3 tkinter gui not responding

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I am new to programming and I apologize if this is an obvious mistake. I am writing a gui on tkinter using python 3.5 on Mac OsX El Capitan. Here is the code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Title")
        master.resizable(False, False)
        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame1.pack()

        ttk.Label(text="Organism").grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.organism_picker = ttk.Combobox(self.frame1, values=("Drosophila     melanogaster",
                                                             "Danio rerio",
                                                             "Caenorhabditis     elegans",
                                                             "Rattus     norvegicus",
                                                             "Mus musculus",
                                                             "Homo sapiens"))  
        self.organism_picker.grid(row=2, column=0)

        ttk.Label(text="Core gene symbol:").grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.core = ttk.Entry(self.frame1)
        self.core.grid(row=4, column=0)


root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this the program enters the main loop, but the gui window never appears and the launcher is not reponding.
I tried to reinstall python 3, installed ActiveTcl, tried using ActivePython instead. Nut none of it worked.

Thank you all in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with your code is that you forgot to *attach* the two labels to the the main widget `self.frame1`.

To fix that, modify them as follow:

```
#Attach the 2 labels to self.frame1
ttk.Label(self.frame1,text="Organism").grid(row=1, column=0) 
ttk.Label(self.frame1,text="Core gene symbol:").grid(row=3, column=0)
```

## Demo

After doing that, you will get this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should not use pack() and grid() as this will generate a geometry manager conflict as pointed out in this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

try changing:

```
 self.frame1.pack()
```

to:

```
 self.frame1.grid()
```

In this case I would suggest using pack overall, since this is a fairly simple layout. please refer to [this guide](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm):

> When to use the Pack Manager
>
> Compared to the grid manager, the pack manager is somewhat limited,
>   but it’s much easier to use in a few, but quite common situations:
>
> Put a widget inside a frame (or any other container widget), and have
>   it fill the entire frame Place a number of widgets on top of each
>   other Place a number of widgets side by side

AND FINALLY:

> Note: Don’t mix grid and pack in the same master window. Tkinter will
>   happily spend the rest of your lifetime trying to negotiate a solution
>   that both managers are happy with. Instead of waiting, kill the
>   application, and take another look at your code. A common mistake is
>   to use the wrong parent for some of the widgets.